# Even though the first element in "23486" is equal to 2, it does not enter to if condition

Tags: c, string, pointers

In below code it does not enter the if condition even though (in my opinion) the comparison is true. It might have something to do with the string elements but I couldn't come up with a solution.
If someone can help that would be more than appriciated.
Thank you indeed.
Note:  The code is supposed to find the frequency of each digit in the given string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
 
    char *str="4655";
    int cnt;
    int len = strlen(str);
    
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        cnt = 0;
        printf("j = %d\t", j);
        for(char i = 0; i < len; i++){
            printf("%c\t",*(str+i));
            if(*(str+i) == j){
                printf("str+i=%c, j = %c", *(str+i), j); //
                cnt++;
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n", cnt);
        
    }  
}
```

Comment: This code wouldn't compile.

Comment: `== j` should be  `== ('0'+j)` . The same goes for the last `printf` argument.

Comment: @Ferda Ömeri What does the magic number 10 mean in this for loop  for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){ ?!

Comment: So sorry, some technical problems while copy pasting @BoR

Comment: Move the `printf` to be outside the `if` and you will see the values are not the same. It is the difference between `2` the integer and `'2'` the ascii character.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow it was supposed to be 'len' sir, sorry. All this error occure since I have tried many ways in order to debug

Comment: `*(str+i)` -> `str[i]` is more readable

Comment: @littleadv So sorry, I edited it now it compiles

Comment: What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks a bunch. I think that saved me.

Comment: @BoR The code is supposed to find the frequency of each digit in the given string. And I think '0'+ j solves it.

Answer (score 0):

Change these two lines in your code:

```
    char *str="234655";  // was "4655"
```

and

```
if((*(str+i))-'0' == j){  // was if(*(str+i) == j){
```

Seems are trying to comapre a character ASCII value with it's bininary representativ. The `-'0'` adjusts that.

You could also do it the other way around:

```
if((*(str+i)) == '0'+j){
```

But, as others have mentioned, you still have other problems with the code but this solves the `if`-statement not ever being true.

Comment: I got it. Such a newbie mistake, just as I am.

Comment: Thank you, it solved the problem. But if you are able to tell me the other problems I would appriciate.

Comment: @FerdaÖmeri, just ask a new question if you still have issues with your program.

Comment: No, no any other questions for now. In your answer you have said that I have other problems with the code. I would like to improve it